# Как отсортировать список без учета регистра , в groovy

Tags: groovy

Сейчас есть такая проверка:

```
assert list == list.sort(false)
```

но она учитывает регистр..

как сделать чтобы не было учета регистра?

Comment: sort({x, y -> x.compareIgnoreCase(y)})

Comment: list.sort({x, y -> x.compareIgnoreCase(y)})                                                   Method threw 'org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException' exception.

Comment: `compareToIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 2):

решил вопрос так:

```
    list.toSorted(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
```